# Oracle 11g, how to speed up an 'in' query

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, view, oracle11g

I was trying to create a view and needed to create a column that shows if the 'somenumber' column exists on other table or not. The code below worked but very slowly. Is it possible to declare a table as (select someNumber from veryYugeTable) and check on that one instead of sending this query for every single record or using some other way to speed up the view?

```
case 
         when someOtherTable.someNumber in(select someNumber from veryYugeTable) then 'exists' 
         else 'doesn't exist' 
end as "someColumn"
```

Comment: use left join veryYugeTable on someNumber = someOtherTable.someNumber then change the casewhen clause to veryYugeTable.Column is null then 'doesn't exist' else 'exits'

Comment: Please post the view query and the explain plan of it. Without seeing the problem is not easy to provide a solution. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database?answertab=active#tab-top) some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find you get some benefit with scalar subquery caching if you do something like:

```
coalesce((select 'exists'
          from   veryyugetable vyt
          where  vyt.somenumber = someOtherTable.someNumber
          and    rownum = 1),
         'doesn''t exist') somecolumn
```

N.B. the `and rownum = 1` is not necessary if `vyt.somenumber` is a unique column. Also, I nth the suggest to index the `vyt.somenumber` column.

Answer (score 1):

The query looks fine. You should have an index on `veryYugeTable.someNumber`.

Sometimes the optimizer handles correlated subqueries better than non-correlated ones, so you can try:

```
case
  when exists 
  (
    select * 
    from veryYugeTable
    where veryYugeTable.someNumber = someOtherTable.someNumber
  ) then 'exists' 
  else 'doesn''t exist' 
end as "someColumn"
```

(Well, as this query does exactly the same as yours, the optimizer should get to the same execution plan, but this is not always the case.)

But as mentioned: Make sure first to have that index.

Comment: Thanks, index seems a fine idea.

Answer (score 0):

use left join instead of putting the in clause in select:

```
left join veryYugeTable on someNumber = someOtherTable.someNumber
```

adjust your case when statement as follow:

```
case 
         when veryYugeTable.OtherColumn is null then 'doesn''t exist' 
         else 'exist' 
end as "someColumn"
```

Comment: This will fail (= produce dups) if the `someNumber` is not a PK (unique) in the table `veryYugeTable`

Comment: Sadly someNumber isn't PK at veryYugeTable.